# react big calendar remove first row which is not in use

Tags: reactjs

How can I remove first row of react big calendar. I tried 'showMultiDayTimes' prop to false but not working.
http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#prop-showMultiDayTimes

Comment: How is it not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First row is to show events which spans multiple days.
So if you don't want to show, you can override css to remove.

```
.rbc-allday-cell {
  display: none !important;
}
```

https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar/issues/203